# jQuery not working as it should

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to follow along the demo source code for the [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) jQuery method, but the div cannot be dragged.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#draggable").draggable();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
        <p>Drag me around</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is on a freshly created ASP.Net MVC3 application default start project. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to include jQuery UI.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. I somehow completely forgot to add that .js library. Thanks!